# JavaFX : Should I test for a control already being Disabled before Disabling it?

Tags: javafx, focus, javafx-2, javafx-8

Best practice question:
I'm concerned that disabling an already disabled control may unexpectedly change the focus to another control. If this is not the case, then testing for the control being already disabled is unnecessary overhead.

What control gets focus if you disable the control that currently has focus? The first control, the preceding or next control relative to the control being disabled?

Comment: Could not simply ask the control for it's state before setting it to disabled?

Comment: Umm... -  I could. I'm asking if that is necessary.

Comment: what happened when you tried it? use 3 buttons, focus the second and disable it ... doing so at least gives you circumstancial evidence :-) AFAIK, the focusowner can't be never disabled - so disabling a disabled control can't change focus

Comment: having a hard time to find relevant api doc: node.disabled == ! getting mouse/key events, node.focused == have input, node.requestFocus == not eligible if disabled ... but nothing on what happens if the focused node gets disabled ...